# Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 sub.GetHistoryForKey only returns current value

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am using Hyperledger Fabric basic-network configuration. When I develop the chaincode, I call [sub.GetHistoryForKey()](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetHistoryForKey), but I only get the current value. According the documentation, I should set core.ledger.history.enableHistoryDatabase to true. But now I don't have `core.yaml` file, where I should set `core.ledger.history.enableHistoryDatabase`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the byfn example, you still have a core.yaml. It's just within the docker container running the peer.

First use `docker ps` to find the peer container's id.

Then run `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash` to enter the container.

From there `cd /etc/hyperledger/fabric/`. The `core.yaml` file you are looking for exists there.